# How to make Kivy ActionBar Button do something on click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, kivy

I am trying to create a menu bar and the button need to do some function.
**EDITED**
This is what I tried:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.actionbar import *
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<TitleBar>:
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Hello'
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
            ActionButton:
                important: True
                text: 'Important'
                on_press: app.updater()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn2'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn3'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn4'
            ActionGroup:
                dropdown_width:200
                text: 'Group1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn5'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn6'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn7'
""")
class TitleBar(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TetraApp(App):


    def build(self):
        Window.size=(875,575)
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1)
        #Window.borderless=True
        #return Label(text="Hello Kivy!")
        return TitleBar()
    def updater(self):
        return Label(text='Hello')
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=TetraApp()
    app.run()
```

Running on Python 3.7.5 Windows 10
Now it Works Button the Label is not printed It doesnt display any error but the label isin't being shown. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the method

```
def updater(self):
        return self.root.add_widget(Label(text='Hello'))
```

Comment: Thats One-Line Perfection!

Comment: but how do you change the actionbar width?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to display a Label, you should add it to your Layout by using:
`add_widget()`. So in your case it would be `add_widget(Label(text='Hello'))`. But you still need to specify to what you want to add the widget, so you need to reference to the FloatLayout since you want to add it there. So I think it's better to put your updater method inside the Titlebar class and then do like this:

```
class TitleBar(FloatLayout):

    def updater(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello'))
```

You should then also change `on_press: app.updater()` to `on_press: root.updater()`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ths answer is Perfect